# Isolating read and write in multithreaded

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading

In a multithreaded application. I have a bunch of function that loop through a collection to read the information. I also have a bunch of function that modifies that same collection.

I’m looking for a way to isolate all the read and the write together. I don’t want a write to be done while a read is in progress. I was thinking of using SyncLock on the collection object but this will block multiple read trying to work in parallel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered [ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx)? You might want to [check that using it is faster than a simple Monitor lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407238/readerwriterlockslim-vs-monitor) though. Do not consider the older ReaderWriterLock. Here's what Jeffrey Richter has to say about it:

> The Microsoft® .NET Framework Class
>   Library includes a ReaderWriterLock
>   class in the System.Threading
>   namespace that lets you obtain
>   multiple-reader/single-writer
>   semantics. While it is nice that a
>   class like this exists, there are
>   several problems with its
>   implementation and I recommend you do
>   not use it.