# Does a lock around a write guarantee fresh read in another thread? (.Net, memory model)

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency, locking, memory-model

Say I have a property whose setter is protected by a lock, but without any lock around the getter, e.g.

```
private long _myField;
public long MyProperty
{
    get { return _myField; }
    set { lock(whatever) _myField = value; }
}
```

In addition to synchronizing writes (but not reads), the lock, or rather Monitor.Exit, should cause a [volatile write](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/volatility.shtml). Let's now say we have two threads A and B, and the following sequence happens:

1. A reads the current value of `MyProperty`.
2. B writes a new value to `MyProperty`.
3. A reads the current value of `MyProperty` again.

Q: Is A now guaranteed to see the new value? Or did our lock just ensure that B writes to main memory in a timely manner, but not that other threads read a fresh value? Or could the answer even depend on whether we're running in .Net 2+ or a "weaker" ECMA implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, since the read does not have the explicit memory barrier, it is not "guaranteed" to see the new value.

You can use a [`ReaderWriterLockSlim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx) to insure that a) the writes lock each other and b) the reads always pickup the new value.

```
private readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim _myFieldLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
private long _myField;
public long MyProperty
{
    get 
    {
        _myFieldLock.EnterReadLock();
        try
        {
            return _myField;
        }
        finally
        {
            _myFieldLock.ExitReadLock();
        }
    }
    set
    {
        _myFieldLock.EnterWriteLock();
        try
        {
            _myField = value;
        }
        finally
        {
            _myFieldLock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: The OP code `value = _myField` looks like a mistake, so i changed it to `_myField = value`.

Comment: What's the point of the RWLS?  The lock keyword in the getter and setter will work just as well for two threads, with *lots* less overhead.

Comment: @hans-passant What if there are more threads reading at the same time?

Comment: @hans-passant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/407238/readerwriterlockslim-vs-monitor Don't know if the answer is correct though, Have you experienced better performance with the `lock` vs `ReaderWriterLockSlim`?

Comment: @scrum - a mistake indeed, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If you used Interlocked.Read in the getter you should always read the new value. See [Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx) for more information about memory fences